# Why is it called a "family" of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

If I'm not mistaken, a "family of sets" is just $f:I\mapsto X$. My question is: why they decided to call it a "family" of sets? What's the intuitive picture that made some guy call this a $\textbf{family}$?

Comment: What do you think is X in your description? Family is a lot like collection, group or set, but it doesn’t have the same connotations necessarily. You generally try to pick terms that way.

Comment: Maybe someone got tired of saying "set of sets". Seriously, though,  it's easier to keep your thoughts organized  when you give  different kinds of names. like family, or collection, etc., to  some sets. Intuitively the members of a family of sets ought to be related, in that they are all the sets with some specified property.

Comment: Generally a family of sets is  the same thing as a set of sets. And in pure set-theory it's redundant because everything that exists is a set.

Comment: Often the sets in the family are related in some way.  They are not just a random collection of sets that are the image of $f$.  The powerset of some set $A$ is a family-they are all subsets of $A$.  They might be partial functions from $\omega$ to $\{0,1\}$..  They might be lots of things.

Comment: Thanks all. Especially @RossMillikan. It was exactly the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Why do we say tens/hundreds/thousands/millions/etc, and not tens/tens of tens/tens of tens of tens/tens of tens of tens of tens of tens of tens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *family* of things is certainly different from a *set* of things.

If $A$ is a nonempty set then its elements $x$ are not "organized" in any way. Each thing $x$ you can think of either is an element of $A$, or is not an element of $A$, period. Given $A$ you can, e.g., form the set ${A\choose 3}$of all three-element subsets of $A$. This is a *set* of sets, but not a family of sets.

In order to obtain a family of things $x$ you need an index set $I$ and a function $f$ that produces for each $\iota\in I$ one such thing $x_\iota:=f(\iota)$. The resulting "data structure" is then called a *family* of things, and is  denoted by $\bigl(x_\iota\bigr)_{\iota\in I}$.

As an example, if $X$ is an arbitrary nonempty set and ${\cal P}(X)$ its power set then an $$f:\>I\to{\cal P}(X),\quad\iota\to A_\iota$$ produces a *family of subsets* of $X$. This family is denoted by $\bigl(A_\iota\bigr)_{\iota\in I}$. Note that the same subset $A\subset X$ may occur several times in this family, whereas in a set of subsets it would occur at most once.

The functions $f$ appearing in this explanation are not interesting per se; therefore they do not appear in the notation. But every time we talk about a "family" such an $f$ is looming in the background.

Comment: Perfect, this explanation is compatible with the book I'm reading (Bourbaki's set theory)

Comment: One quick question: when you say "the same subset may occur several times", is it the same as saying "several members of $I$ map to the same element in ${\cal P}(X)$"?

Comment: Also, is it correct to say that a "family of sets" is exactly the same as a mapping but the terminology is used when the codomain is a set of sets? Thanks.

Comment: @Ali: Why on earth are you reading that book?

Comment: Concerning your first question: Yes. The $n$-tuple $(5,1,-2,1,4)$ is a family of integers, indexed by the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Concerning your second question: We use the word "family" instead of "mapping" when we are not interested in the exact $f$ and its properties, but in the "list" of produced objects.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Sorry to bother, Would you please shed a light on my concern as well, thank you. In your case, suppose the indexed family $(A_\iota)_{\iota \in I}$ contains the same subset $A\subset X$ only once, under such circumstance $(A_\iota)_{\iota \in I}$ preserves "ordered property" only compare to $\{A_\iota\}_{\iota \in I}$. Then, if I can write $(A_\iota)_{\iota \in I} \subset \mathcal P(X)$?

Comment: @LJNG: You should not do that. The object $\bigl(A_\iota\bigr)_{\iota\in I}$ is a *list* of things. This list maybe has a certain structure, e.g., it could be a binomial tree with the $A_\iota$ sitting on the vertices of this tree. On the other hand, a subset of ${\cal P}(X)$ is just a set whose elements are subsets of $X$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thank you for your reply. Really Appreciate for your time. I am reading Schilling's *Measures, Integrals and Martingales*, he defines $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr A$ on a set $X$ is a family of subsets of X with one property that $(A_n)_{n \in N}\subset \mathscr A\implies \bigcup A_{n}\in\mathscr A$. In this case, is it a matter of notation $(A_n)_{n\in N}=\{A_n\}_{n\in N}$? When we bring up the term' indexed family of sets', don't we really care about the ordered of the sets in such family(e.g viewing as a tuple)?